# HTML markup is not working for database fields in RDLC report in c#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2010

I have some Text in database with HTML tags and styles. So I want to show it in RDLC report with HTML formatting. But when I am setting HTML Markup of my database field it's not showing HTML formatting only plain text with HTML tags.

But working fine in Simple TextBox.

What I have tried.
1) select field in Placeholder and right click
2) Placeholder Properties
3) In HTML Markup --> HTML-Interpret HTML tags as style

But same thing is working fine in TextBox
Here is  my Code
HTML

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="600px" 
            Width="1000px">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
```

And C#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report.rdlc");
            DataSet Ds = new DMedicare();
            Ds = GetData();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DMedicare", Ds.Tables[0]);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please include some code?

Comment: @MartinM Check my Update